# User-Token which decode/decryption algorithm is that?

Tags: encoding, web-applications, base64, token

I have a string, but what I want to know is how this is generated?

`3C+msMRwFDOcepm960C2kUfeFdBe2WoWLFATI+u7EKiFt9nqdPuI6nXIByUhBeNoCqaivEHp/dHimnfAeT0n7ZsZU6AmJkONCulPOLd8q09i+EzfWhW0GJmnvSIC3YEh5kuZOF62E63f12gjESKwyYVq4Y/iWcAu2TdyueX977U5O4BdLIEbDsmjSUhKLfiH8RvaGZrj4OpggOvpytsqcQ==`

I did some research over the last days, and it seems its an base64 encoding but here we have also special characters in the string like "/+=". The plain text should be `b33912c6-b805-412b-9660-b80186fc3b9f`, but no encoding/encryption method I found online could get the same string.

Which encryption or encoding algorithm is used here?

Comment: it's normal base64 encoding. `=` is a padding character, all others are normal characters from the [base64 table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table)

Comment: thank for that, yes i readed the page at link. but why i cant reproduce the same code with "b33912c6-b805-412b-9660-b80186fc3b9f" or when i try to decode the string the result is just anything else

Comment: I don't know, after decoding I got an array of 320 bytes, much longer than the source.